# How to batch execute SQL query using Hibernate session

Tags: java, hibernate, session

I am using the below set of code for an update:

```
private void updateAvatarPath(Integer param1, String param2, String param3, boolean param4){

        Transaction avatarUpdatePathTransaction = session.beginTransaction();


        String updateQuery = "query goes here with param";

        Query query = session.createSQLQuery(updateQuery);
        query.executeUpdate();

        avatarUpdatePathTransaction.commit();
        session.flush();
    }
```

This function is being called from a loop. So this takes time to update since for each loop it's hitting the DB. Instead of hitting DB every time, to increase the performance I am planning to execute it as batches. But have no idea how to do it.

`session.doWork()` is one of the solutions which I got. I want to know any other option available to do it.

Answer (score 2):

You should move `Transaction avatarUpdatePathTransaction = session.beginTransaction();` before the start of your loop and `avatarUpdatePathTransaction.commit();` after the end of your loop.

The recommended pattern is to have one session per "unit of work", in your case this seems to be modifying multiple entities in a single session/transaction.

The `session.flush();` is not necessary I think, committing the transaction should flush the session